# Uncaught TypeError: d3.arc(...).outerRadius(...).innerRadius(...).text is not a function

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've encountered an error while coding my chart on my "card" bootstrap.
The thing is I only want the label to show on my pie chart but the problem is console on google chrome says "Uncaught TypeError: d3.arc(...).outerRadius(...).innerRadius(...).text is not a function"
In which i don't get why.

Below is my code for the pie-chart:

```
var data = [
    {"platform": "Android", "percentage": 40.11},
    {"platform": "Windows", "percentage": 36.69},
    {"platform": "iOS", "percentage": 13.06}
];


var svgCirWidth = 600, svgCirHeight = 300, radius = Math.min(svgCirWidth, svgCirHeight) / 2;

const pieContainer = d3.select("#pieChart")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", svgCirWidth)
.attr("height", svgCirHeight);

//create group element to hold pie chart

var g = pieContainer.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + 170 + "," + radius + ")");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d){
    return d.percentage;
});

var path = d3.arc()
.outerRadius(radius)
.innerRadius(0);

var arc = g.selectAll("arc")
.data(pie(data))
.enter() //means keeps looping in the data
.append("g");

arc.append("path")
.attr("d", path)
.attr("fill", function(d){
    return color(d.data.percentage);
})

var label = d3.arc()
.outerRadius(radius)
.innerRadius(0)
.text(function(d){
    return d;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[`d3.arc`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#arcs) returns a path's `d` attribute. This cannot contain text.

In SVG, text must be enclosed inside `<text>`.

Since your variable `arc` is a selection of a `g` element, you could append `<text>` to it:

```
arc.append('text')
     .text(/* ... */)
```

### Edit after receiving a comment that "it still won't work"

Please be specific whenever reporting problems, in order to receive proper help: is there any error message? What is the observed behaviour, and what was the expected one?

Using `arc.append('text')` seems to work just fine.

#### Debugging tip

It is often helpful to use `console.log` as shown below to see what is going on:

```
arc.append('text')
  .text(function(d){
    console.log('text', d)
    return d;
  })
```

The code above will show that `d` is an object, this is why the labels are shown in the page as `[object object]`.

I assume that the desired behaviour is rather to show the platform and percentage values.

Then instead of `return d`, we know thanks to the console.log output that we should rather use `d.data.platform` and `d.data.percentage`:

```
return d.data.platform + ': ' + d.data.percentage;
```

#### Labels placement

Another issue observed is that all labels are overlapping. This is normal, no position has been defined for them.

A quick use of search engine shows us [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/user2314737/kvz8uev8/2/), where [`arc.centroid`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#arc_centroid) is used together with `text-anchor: middle` to position each label in a suitable location.

Solution is illustrated in the snipped below.

```js
var data = [
    {"platform": "Android", "percentage": 40.11},
    {"platform": "Windows", "percentage": 36.69},
    {"platform": "iOS", "percentage": 13.06}
];


var svgCirWidth = 600, svgCirHeight = 300, radius = Math.min(svgCirWidth, svgCirHeight) / 2;

const pieContainer = d3.select("#pieChart")
.append("svg")
.attr("width", svgCirWidth)
.attr("height", svgCirHeight);

//create group element to hold pie chart

var g = pieContainer.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + 170 + "," + radius + ")");

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);

var pie = d3.pie().value(function(d){
    return d.percentage;
});

var path = d3.arc()
.outerRadius(radius)
.innerRadius(0);

var arc = g.selectAll("arc")
.data(pie(data))
.enter() //means keeps looping in the data
.append("g")

arc.append("path")
.attr("d", path)
.attr("fill", function(d){
    return color(d.data.percentage);
})

arc.append('text')
  .text(function(d){
    return d.data.platform + ': ' + d.data.percentage;
  })
  .attr('transform', function(d){
    return 'translate(' + path.centroid(d) + ')'
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'middle')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.15.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="pieChart"></div>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for answering but it still won't work :(